# SSL handshakeCompleted never called

Tags: java, security, ssl, encryption

I am trying to send data from my client to my server. Therefore I am using TSL.

I created the certificates and these are loaded without any troubles.

The connection is established, but the handshake between the client and the server is never called, and the handshakeCompleted is never called.

Client:

```
        char[] password = "Password".toCharArray();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        trustStore.load(activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore), password);
        Log.i("Update", "Loaded trust certificate");

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        Log.i("Update", "Loaded trustManagerFactory");

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        keyStore.load(activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore), password);
        Log.i("Update", "Loaded key certificate");

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
        Log.i("Update", "Loaded keyManagerFactory");

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        Log.i("Update", "Loaded SSLContext");

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        final SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);
        Log.i("Update", "Loaded SSL 

        socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener(){
            @Override
            public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent handshakeCompletedEvent){
                try{
                    Log.i("Update", "Did handshake");

                    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    Log.i("Update", "Writer");
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    Log.i("Update", "Reader");

                    while(isRunning){
                        try{
                            writer.println("Test");
                            writer.flush();
                            Log.i("DATA", "DATA SENT");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                    socket.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        socket.startHandshake();
```

Server:

```
        char[] password = "Password".toCharArray();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/security/keystore.jks"), password);

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(7826);
        System.out.println("Accepting connections now...");

        while(true){
            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
            socket.setUseClientMode(false);
        socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(handshakeCompletedEvent -> {
            try{
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                while(running){
                    if(!socket.isConnected() || socket.isClosed()){
                        disconnect();
                        return;
                    }
                    for(Iterator<String> pendingIterator = pendingMessages.iterator(); pendingIterator.hasNext();){
                        String message = pendingIterator.next();
                        pendingIterator.remove();
                        writer.println(message); writer.flush();
                    }

                    //Auto decrypt when message arrives, but no thread blocking
                    if(reader.ready()){
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        socket.startHandshake();
        }
```

As you can see I am waiting on both sides for the handshakeComplete, using it only on the client or only on the server side doesn't work either

Comment: I think you need to put the listener *before* you explicitly start the handshake. Can you adjust the code and try?

Comment: Both will start the TLS handshake thinking that they are the TLS client and wait for the other side to be the TLS server - and thus wait forever. You have to put one side into server mode before starting the handshake: i.a. do  `socket.setUseClientMode(false);` after the `serverSocket.accept()`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I set the listener before the handshake
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work!

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added the piece of code

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work!

Comment: It would be more useful if you would also update the question to reflect the code you use now instead of just describing in the comments what code changes you did. Also, adding output from [debugging the SSL handshake](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) from both sides of the connection to your question might be useful too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich After restarting the application a second time, it finally worked, the handshake is called. I know I should create a new question for this, but could you help me with a quick fix? On the server side it can open the inputstream and the outputstream of the socket, but on the client side neither of them can be opened. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: No, I don't have any ideas about this.